# Expression inside a static cast

Tags: c++, casting, integer-arithmetic

I wrote a code like this :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<static_cast<float>(5/9)*9;
    cout<<static_cast<float>(5)/9*9;
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output :55

Original output :05

Why the first static cast statement turned to 0 ?

Answer (score 5):

In this sub-expression

```
(5/9)
```

of this statement

```
cout<<static_cast<float>(5/9)*9;
```

there is used the integer arithmetic. The result of the sub-expression is 0. This result is converted to the type float.

```
static_cast<float>( 0 )
```

That is the casting is applied to the primary sub-expression in parentheses after its evaluation.

In the second statement

```
cout<<static_cast<float>(5)/9*9;
```

that is in fact equivalent to

```
cout<< 5.0f/9*9;
```

in the sub-expression

```
static_cast<float>(5)/9
```

or that is the same

```
5.0f / 9
```

there is used the arithmetic with floating numbers and the result is not equal to 0.